# Nested ShortCode works inside the_content, but not outside of it

Tags: shortcode, the-content

community; 
 I've spent all weekend trying to crack a problem that so far eludes me. 
 On a multisite implementation, I'm using a simple homegrown plugin to include textbits that are the same across subsites (such as staffers' bio bits e.g.).

While this plugin has no problems to resolve nested calls of itself inside the_content, it falls on is face outside the_content, specifically in those author boxes that are either appended after the_content on single posts, or prepended before the_loop on author archives by the theme we're using.

I'm attaching a little screenshot to illustrate that it's working inside but failing outside the content: [image: the upper portion shows the include inside the include to work as expected, the highlighted section in the author box below where it fails.]

, hoping someone might be able to point me towards what I'm obviously missing.

Thank you very much in advance for any help you may able to provide. Cheers -

Comment: If you're entering a shortcode outside of the main post content then that area needs to support shortcodes. Shortcodes only work if the output is run through the `apply_shortcodes()` (or `do_shortcode()`). If you're using a theme or plugin for displaying author bios then that plugin or theme needs to use this function to explicitly support shortcodes. You will need to contact its author to see if there's a way you can do this yourself or if they can add it for you.

Comment: Hi, Jacob; 
oddly, there already is a
add_filter( 'get_the_author_description', 'do_shortcode');
at work; which I had hoped to have illustrated in the original post.  

The weird thing is that _first_level shortcodes do get resolved, only deeper levels aren't. 

Is there perhaps a non-destructive way to run the output rendered per  get_the_author_description thru a second round of shortcode-resloution?

Comment: HA! YES!! You pointed me to the right detail :D 

I simply added a 
add_filter( 'get_the_author_description', 'apply_shortcodes');
after the 
add_filter( 'get_the_author_description', 'do_shortcode');

and that bloody well DID IT! :))) 

thanks a ton for the dcisive spark of inspiration! (y)

Comment: [**resolved** per comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/411429/nested-shortcode-works-inside-the-content-but-not-outside-of-it#comment600880_411429)s :) Cheers!